# I cannot write the data pulled from the API (Flutter)

Tags: api, flutter

I pull data from the exchange rates API. I can display my captured data in the console, but not in a text box in the middle of the page.

Here my api : http://batuhandelice.com/doviz.json

Here my model:

```html
import 'dart:convert';

List<Doviz> dovizFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Doviz>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Doviz.fromJson(x)));

String dovizToJson(List<Doviz> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Doviz {
  Doviz({
    this.alis,
    this.satis,
    this.degisim,
  });

  String alis;
  String satis;
  String degisim;

  factory Doviz.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Doviz(
        alis: json["alis"],
        satis: json["satis"],
        degisim: json["degisim"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "alis": alis,
        "satis": satis,
        "degisim": degisim,
      };
}
```

And here my UI:

```html
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:genel_para/models/doviz.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class DovizKurlari extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WordListPageState createState() => _WordListPageState();
}

class _WordListPageState extends State<DovizKurlari> {
  Future<List<Doviz>> data;

  Future<List<Doviz>> getDoviz() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse("myURL"));

    Map<String, dynamic> data =
        new Map<String, dynamic>.from(json.decode(response.body));
    print(data['EUR']);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Text('$data'),
        ),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

print (data ['EUR']) this way I can print the data for Euro to consol, but I cannot print it in the text box.

Comment: use Text(data['EUR'].toString())

Comment: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Future<List<Doviz>>'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, change the type of the data variable on top to map then set it on the method:

Call the getDoviz on initState then user setState:

```
 Map<String, dynamic> data;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getDoviz();
}

  Future<List<Doviz>> getDoviz() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse("myURL"));

    setState(() {
      data =
        new Map<String, dynamic>.from(json.decode(response.body));
    });
    
    print(data['EUR']);
  }
```

then you can call like this, for example:

```
Text(data != null ? data['EUR']['satis'].toString() : 'Waiting result')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but now it doesn't write to the console, it still doesn't work.Still not typing in both console and text box. Error : The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: [] ("EUR")

Comment: Call the method on the initState and check if is null on the widget.

Comment: Oh my god this is working. Thank you very much indeed, you saved my whole day.

Answer (score 0):

The Text widget takes a String. You are trying to pass in a Map.

Instead of

```
Text('$data');
```

Try

```
Text('${data['EUR']['satis']'});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. Too many positional arguments: 1 expected, but 2 found. I got the error

Comment: My bad I forgot to add `'`. I updated my answer.